# Symfony 3.2 parameter defined into parameters.php is not defined in PDO session configuration

Tags: symfony, session, symfony-3.2

I'm using symfony 3.2, i want to have a dynamic database connection, so i 'm importing a file parameters.php in my config.yml file :

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.php }
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
```

In the parameters.php i am defining database_name :

```
$container->setParameter('database_name', $dbName);
```

This work fine with native file session, but when i'm using pdo session following the symfony example :

```
services:
    session.handler.pdo:
        class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
        public:    false
        arguments:
           - 'mysql:host=%database_host%;port=%database_port%;dbname=%database_name%'
           - { db_username: '%database_user%', db_password: '%database_password%' }
```

I'have an error on compilation :

```
 [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException]
  A string value must be composed of strings and/or numbers, but found parameter "database_name" of type boolean inside string value "mysql:host=%database_host%;port=%database_port%;dbname=%database_name%".
```

It's like symfony don't know the parameter "database_name".

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it's seems not to be the way to do it ...
Finally i've create a Custom ConnectionFactory

```
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\ConnectionFactory;

class MyConnectionFactory extends ConnectionFactory {

    public function createConnection(array $params, \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration $config = null, \Doctrine\Common\EventManager $eventManager = null, array $mappingTypes = array()) {



      // Determine here params ....

        $params['dbname'] = $dbName;
        $params['host'] = $dbHost
        $params['user'] = $dbUser
        $params['password'] = $dbCode;

        return parent::createConnection($params, $config, $eventManager, $mappingTypes);
    }
```

It's work !